# java.lang.NullPointerException about gps api?

Tags: android, api, gps

as the title i have a question about the gps api
follow is my code

```
 LocationManager loctionManager; 
                 String contextService=Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
                 loctionManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(contextService); 
                 Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                    criteria.setBearingRequired(false); 
                    criteria.setCostAllowed(true); 
                    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
                    String provider = loctionManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); 
                    Location location = loctionManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


                     double a=location.getLatitude();
                    double b=location.getLongitude();
Log.d(""+a,""+b);
```

then the error is java.lang.NullPointerException
anyone can help me?thx

Comment: r u test this application in emulator ?

Comment: please open DDMS from eclipse . In DDMS there is emulator control . In that there is one Location Control set manually latitude and longitude and press send button then please run your application and see what you get .

Comment: please run your application in device ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` can return null you need to ensure it does not.

In order to get a Location you need at first to set permission in your Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Then in your code you need to listen for location avalability. You do that by registering a `LocationListener`. The activity will display, and when Android will have a location for you it will call you back.

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    //Do what you want with your coordinates
}
loctionManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS, 100, 1, locationListener);
```

If you are using the emulator and not a real device you need to force a location, you can use DDMS inside Eclipse to send a fake location:

[image: Send a fake location to an Android Emulator]